# C# Combobox move item to bottom of the list

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need to add "Select more..." to the bottom of the combobox items, like it done on SQL 2008 servers selector. Trying like this:

```
        List<string> srvList = new List<string>();
        srvList.Add("ff");
        srvList.Add("jj");
        srvList.Add("pp");
        srvList.Add("<Select more...>");
        ComboBoxServs.Items.AddRange(srvList.ToArray<String>());
```

But "Select more..." appears at the top of items.

Comment: Are you using simple ComboBox which is provided by .NET?

Comment: Yes, I am using ComboBox from WinForms

Answer (score 3):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx) says:

> If the Sorted property of the ComboBox is set to true, **the items are
>   inserted into the list alphabetically**. Otherwise, the items are
>   inserted in the order they occur within the array.

Try to set `Sorted` property to `false`:

```
    ComboBoxServs.Sorted = false;
    List<string> srvList = new List<string>();
    srvList.Add("ff");
    srvList.Add("jj");
    srvList.Add("pp");
    srvList.Add("<Select more...>");
    ComboBoxServs.Items.AddRange(srvList.ToArray<String>());
```

Comment: It is working, but I need sorted list. Select more... should always be at the bottom

Comment: What if you set `Sorted` to `true` after adding items?

Comment: Select more... moves on top

Comment: Then you should sort the values *before* you're inserting them. There is no way to sort a particular set of items in `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the index of `Insert` method of `Combobox` control

```
 myComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "Select more");
```

hope that help.
you may Refer [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/762a58f5-667d-4e97-a107-86312942f966) also